# QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES - Do i need to display permission dialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, package, android-permissions

I need to get packages installed on phone. I know there is QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission.
Do I need to display popup for user when he can allow/deny permission for my app?

Answer (score 0):

No, the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` is install time permission.

If you need only the installed applications with a launcher activity you can use this query instead of the permission:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```